# Plotting data using R where first column is time in irregular intervals

Tags: r, time-series

How would I plot data in R when the first column is time itself and sampled at irregular intervals?

e.g.

```
      time value
1 00:00:00     3
2 00:00:03     4
3 00:00:07     5
...
5 23:59:59     2
```

I've looked at ts to plot data using `plot.ts` but my first column itself cannot be expressed as increasing time say 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 in 1 second intervals due to missing data. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'm very new to R and I apologize if I'm missing something obvious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to convert `time` to an actual date/time representation and plot `value` against it. R will take care of the spacing etc, e.g.: assuming your dataset is called `dat`:

```
plot(as.POSIXct(dat$time,"%H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"), dat$value)
```

[image]